# Why can't the discord bot join the channel?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm creating a simple bot that should enter the voice channel on the `!play` command and play a random track from the "music" directory. But there is a problem in the line `vc = await voice_channel.connect()`, I think. Because he reacts to the command and enters the voice channel, but the program does not go further at all. Those. the print does not print, the music does not play, and so on. Here is the code itself:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


# Bot readiness check
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')


# Command to play music
@bot.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    vc = await voice_channel.connect()

    print('Connected')

    # Picking a random file from a directory
    music_files = os.listdir('music')
    random_song = os.path.join('music', random.choice(music_files))

    # Playing an audio file
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(random_song), after=lambda e: print('Error:', e) if e else None)
    await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {random_song}')

    # Waiting for the end of the track
    while vc.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    # Disconnecting from a voice channel
    await vc.disconnect()
    await ctx.send(f'Finished playing: {random_song}')


bot.run('token')
```

If I understand correctly, then `await` stops the execution of the current program and waits until the function following it is executed. So the problem is in the connection function itself, but the bot enters the channel, which is strange. There is an idea that it doesn’t go all the way, because in the discord, when you enter the channel, you can see many different connections. Could it be that the python environment is preventing it from connecting?

Comment: Maybe some error is happening. Add the line `discord.utils.setup_logging()` to set the default config of logs. This way you can see any error in the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with line  `vc = await voice_channel.connect()` This line is asynchronous, which means that it will return immediately and continue executing the rest of the code, even though the connect() method has not yet finished. May be try using async with in order to ensure that asynchronous operation is completed before rest of code gets executed

Comment: Definitely not. The `await` instruction makes the function wait until that task is completed to continue the code.
However, the compiler may switch to another task (in another function) while waiting for this one to complete. That's the advantage of asynchronous programming: while one command is waiting for the discord's response, another command can be executed.